# Difference between Tishchenko reaction and Meerwein-Ponndorf-Verley reduction

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

For the Tishchenko reaction, Al(OEt)3 is used as reagent where an aldehyde is oxidized as well as reduced, so it's a redox reaction.

Whereas in [Meerwein-Ponndorf-Verley reduction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meerwein%E2%80%93Ponndorf%E2%80%93Verley_reduction), an aldehyde is converted to secondary alcohol and acetone with the same reagent and this reaction is reversible with the [Oppenauer oxidation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppenauer_oxidation).

So, my question is what is the difference between these two reactions i.e what is the difference in mechanism of this reaction that lead to different products or there are some different conditions other than the reagents which changed their products?

Comment: Generally MPV reduction uses $\ce{Al(O^iPr)3}$.

Comment: Okay, but same can be used for Tishenko reaction also ? Is there any specific reason for it's use only in MPV.

Comment: [See here in reactions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_isopropoxide)

Comment: I am not sure, but I think the only difference is the presence or absence of acetone. In MPV reduction, acetone is present so it can go the reduction route, however, in Tischenko there is no acetone present so it goes to disproportionation route. See the mechanisms [here](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/tishchenko-reaction.shtm) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meerwein%E2%80%93Ponndorf%E2%80%93Verley_reduction)

Comment: $\ce{Al(O^iPr)3}$ is used specifically in MPV reduction because $\ce{^iPrOH}$ is the reduced form of the acetone ($\ce{^iPr=O}$). If you look at the mechanism you will see why they do that. If you use something else, you would get a mixture of a lot of compounds. This way there are only 2 components in equilibrium $\ce{^iPr=O +carbonyl<=> ^iPrOH +alcohol}$